# Wrap all array values in single quotes

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this `[6,7,9,13]` how can I change it to `['6','7','9','13']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) can do your job

```
$arr=array(6,7,9,13 );
$new_array = array_map(function($s){return "'".$s."'";},$arr);
```

**Input**

```
$ cat test.php
<?php
$arr=array(6,7,9,13 );
$new_array = array_map(function($s){return "'".$s."'";},$arr);

/* print input */
print_r($arr);

/* print output */
print_r($new_array);
?>
```

**Output**

```
$ php test.php
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 7
    [2] => 9
    [3] => 13
)
Array
(
    [0] => '6'
    [1] => '7'
    [2] => '9'
    [3] => '13'
)
```